# Right wing terror

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I want to make slide for a program we are conducting against right wing terror.

In the slide can I  use ' right terror ' to denote right wing terror ?

Comment: I wouldn't advise it, as 'right' on its own has other meanings.

Comment: When used as an adjective it's spelled with a hyphen:  *right-wing terror*.